# Max product of the three numbers for a given array of size N

Tags: arrays, math

I need to write a  program to find the Max product of three numbers for a given array of size N.
Is there any effective algorithm for this?
I just need to know the algorithm steps. Non of algorithms that i thought works for all the test cases. 
Thanks!
FYI Array may contains +ve, -ve, or zero elements)

Answer (score 33):

Find the three largest numbers in the array (n1, n2, n3) and the two smallest numbers (m1, m2).

The answer is either n1 x n2 x n3 or n1 x m1 x m2

Comment: Why isn't it just n1 x n2 x n3?

Comment: @Ink-Jet because m1 and m2 might be large negative numbers

Comment: @BlueRaja - exclude 0 from what?

Comment: @mobrule Ah, yes. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks! +1 for you.

Comment: One other case not covered in this solution is if all the numbers are negative. Then the maximum product is the product of those three numbers with the SMALLEST modulus.

Comment: @woodchips: Which are the three largest numbers in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The method get the max product of 3 consists in basically find the biggest 3 numbers from the array and the smallest 2 numbers from the array in just 1 iteration over the array. There are of course a large variety of solutions but this is the optimal 1 because the time to solve the problem is O(n), the other solutions time is O(n lg n)

Here is the java code:
by the way there is a guarantee that the input array is non empty and contains minimum 3 elements so there is no need to extra checks for empty and so on.

```
  int solution(int[] a) {
```

/* the minimums initialized with max int to avoid cases with extreme max in array and false minims 0 minimums returned */

int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

int min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

/* the same logic for maximum initializations but of course inverted to avoid extreme minimum values in array and false 0 maximums */

```
    int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

//the iteration over the array

```
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```

//test if max1 is smaller than current array value

```
        if (a[i] > max1) {
```

/* store the max1 current value in a temp var to test it later against the second maximum
here as you can see is a chain of changes if is changed the biggest max we must change the other 2 */

```
            int tempMax1 = max1;
```

//assign the current array value as maximum

```
            max1=a[i];
```

//test tempMax1 former max1 value against max2

```
            if(tempMax1>max2){
```

/* store max2 value in tempMax2 value to test it against max3 and assign it to max 3 if it's bigger */

```
                int tempMax2 = max2;
                max2 =tempMax1;
                if(tempMax2>max3){
                    max3 = tempMax2;
                }
```

/* test to see if tempMax1 is bigger if isn't bigger than max3, this is happening when 
max1 gets a new value and the old value of max1 is equal with max2 but bigger than max3 */

```
            }else{
                if(tempMax1>max3){
                    max3 = tempMax1;
                }
            }
```

/* in case if current a[i] isn't bigger than max1 we test it to see maybe is bigger than second
 max. Then the same logic from above is applied here to max3 */

```
        }else if(a[i]>max2){
            int tempMax2 = max2;
            max2 = a[i];
            if(tempMax2>max3){
                max3 =tempMax2;
            }
```

/* finally if current array value isn't bigger than max1 and max2 maybe is greater than max3 */

```
        }else if(a[i]>max3){
            max3 = a[i];
        }
```

/* The logic from above with maximums is is applied here with minimums but of course inverted to
discover the 2 minimums from current array. */

```
        if (a[i] < min1) {
            int tempMin1 = min1;
            min1 = a[i];
            if (tempMin1 < min2) {
                min2 = tempMin1;
            }
        } else if (a[i] < min2) {
            min2 = a[i];
        }
    }
```

/* after we discovered the 3 greatest maximums and the 2 smallest minimums from the array
we do the 2 products of 3 from the greatest maximum and the 2 minimums . This is necessary
because mathematically the product of 2 negative values is a positive value, and because of
this the product of min1 * min2 * max1 can be greater than max1 * max2 * max3
 and the product built from the the 3 maximums. */

```
    int prod1 = min1 * min2 * max1;
    int prod2 = max1 * max2 * max3;
```

//here we just return the biggest product

```
    return prod1 > prod2 ? prod1 : prod2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of list = (n1, n2, n3...).  You can do this in 3 passes.

```
Let a1 = max (|n_i|) 
Let a2 = max (|n_i|) where n_i != a1
```

Now a1*a2 is either positive, negative or zero.  If zero then there are many solutions;  pick any n_i from the rest of the numbers. If a1*a2 > 0 then pick the largest positive number otherwise smallest negative number.  More succinctly, you can just make one pass through the rest of the list:

```
Let max_product = max (a1*a2*n_i) where n_i != a1 or a2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution in Java:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int result1, result2;

        Arrays.sort(A);
        result1 = A[0] * A[1] * A[A.length-1];
        result2 = A[A.length-1] * A[A.length-2] * A[A.length-3];

        if (result1 >= result2) return result1;
        else return result2;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an efficient solution, but a useful backup to show the use of data structures. Create a max heap and min heap out of these integers. Then delete the root from max heap till you get 3 distinct integers (top 3) and get the least two distinct integers from the min heap. Do the rest of the checks as mentioned in other responses max (max1 * max2 * max3, max1, min1, min2)

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_three_product(a):
a=sorted(a)
max_prod=a[-1]*a[-2]*a[-3]
if a[0]>0:
    return a[-1]*a[-2]*a[-3]
else:
    if a[0]*a[1]<0:
        return max_prod
    elif a[1]*a[2]>0:
        if a[0]*a[1]*a[-1]>max_prod:
            return a[0]*a[1]*a[-1]
        else:
            return max_prod
    else:
        if a[0]*a[1]*a[-1]>max_prod:
            return a[0]*a[1]*a[-1]
        else:
            return max_prod
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Just code is _not_ a useful answer.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I Wrote this simple solution in Python which I was looking and could't find.

```
def ThreeHighestNumbers(arrayOfNumbers):
    PmaxNum1 = 0
    PmaxNum2 = 0 
    PmaxNum3 = 0
    NMinNum1 = 0
    NMinNum2 = 0
    maxNumber = 0

    for num in arrayOfNumbers:
        if num < 0:
            if num < NMinNum1:
                NMinNum2 = NMinNum1
                NMinNum1 = num
            elif num < NMinNum2:
                NMinNum2 = num
        else:
            if num > PmaxNum1:
                PmaxNum3 = PmaxNum2
                PmaxNum2 = PmaxNum1
                PmaxNum1 = num

            elif num > PmaxNum2:
                PmaxNum3 = PmaxNum2
                PmaxNum2 = num

            elif num > PmaxNum3:
                PmaxNum3 = num

    maxNumber = PmaxNum1 * PmaxNum2 * PmaxNum3

    if maxNumber == 0:
        return []

    if maxNumber < PmaxNum1 * NMinNum1 * NMinNum2:
        return [PmaxNum1,NMinNum2,NMinNum1]
    else:
        return [PmaxNum1,PmaxNum2,PmaxNum3]



arraOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,-8,-9,0]
print ThreeHighestNumbers(arraOfNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a BubbleSort procedure and break within three iterations. Take the bottom of three and multiply. That should provide you the solution.

```
int count = 0, j=a.length;  
boolean swap = false; 
do
{
  swap = false; 
  for(int i=1;i<j;i++)
  {
    if(a[i]<a[i-1])
    {
      int t= a[i];
      a[i] = a[i-1];
      a[i-1] = t; 
      swap = true;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(j+" Iteration:"+Arrays.toString(a));
  j--;
  if(swap)
    count++;
} while(swap && count<3); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
return a[a.length-1]*a[a.length-2]*a[a.length-3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Python that gets 100% with O(N*Log(N)) complexity.

```
def solution(A):
    # Implement your solution here

    a_sorted = sorted(A)

    left_product = a_sorted[0] * a_sorted[1]
    right_product = a_sorted[-1] * a_sorted[-2]


    if left_product >= right_product and a_sorted[-1] > 0:
        return left_product * a_sorted[-1]
    else:
        if left_product >= a_sorted[-2] * a_sorted[-3] and a_sorted[-1] > 0:
            return left_product * a_sorted[-1]
        return right_product * a_sorted[-3]
```

Most of this is just checks for edge cases.

First, check that the left_product is larger than the right. Such as with large negative numbers. But we want to make sure the last element is greater than zero.

Ex.

[-3, -2, 0, 1] will return 6.

[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1] will return -20 without the check. We want -6.

Next, we want to make sure that left product is larger than the product of the next two smaller values that are less than the last. We could have a scenario where the left product is smaller than the right, but the largest value is actually from multiplying the left product with the last element in the list.

Ex. [-5, -3, 0, 1, 4, 7] 15 < 28, but the larger value comes from 15 * 7.

Finally, with all negative numbers or positive numbers, the last 3 elements will be largest.

Ex.

[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1] -> -6

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]      -> 60