# How to implement an efficient algorithm for finding the maximum three in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

The task is to find the maximum three in the array (multiplying three numbers so that their products are the largest).

Array length can be up to **1.000.000**

Range of numbers from **-1.000.000 to 1.000.000**

***Question***: I understand that first you need to sort the array by quick sort, and then what condition should I select the numbers?

For example, in the sequence:

```
-17, -12, 1, 3, 4
```

`(-17) * (- 12) * 4` will work, that is, the multiplication of the three most significant positive numbers will be less.

Comment: Also see: [Max product of the three numbers for a given array of size N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187431/max-product-of-the-three-numbers-for-a-given-array-of-size-n)

Comment: By the way, you don't really need to sort the whole array to find the three largest/two smallest elements. For this, you only need to iterate through the array and keep track of two/three maximums. This is an O(N) operiation.

Comment: For larger lists, a simple bubblesort will work, as you need just three iterations to get the three largest numbers on top. You don't care about the rest. Compare the *absolute* values

Comment: default locale, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, for a given sequence, say,

```
 4, 3, 1, -12, -17
```

maximum is either a product of *top* 3 items:

```
4 * 3 * 1 == 12
```

or a product of 2 *bottom* items and the *top* one:

```
-17 * -12 * 4 == 816
```

Here, the second option provides a better outcome, so the answer is `816`. To obtain these top 3 and bottom 2 items you don't have to sort; a simple scan is enough:

```
private static long TopThreeMaximum(IEnumerable<int> values) {
  long Max1 = long.MinValue;
  long Max2 = long.MinValue;
  long Max3 = long.MinValue;

  long Min1 = long.MaxValue;
  long Min2 = long.MaxValue;

  foreach (int value in values) {
    if (value >= Max1) {
      Max3 = Max2;
      Max2 = Max1;
      Max1 = value;
    }
    else if (value >= Max2) {
      Max3 = Max2;
      Max2 = value;
    }
    else if (value > Max3)
      Max3 = value;

    if (Min1 >= value) {
      Min2 = Min1;
      Min1 = value;
    }
    else if (Min2 > value)
      Min2 = value;
  }

  return Math.Max(Max1 * Max2 * Max3, Max1 * Min1 * Min2);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer in most cases. We also might have to consider some edge cases. E.g., what if we have only 2 positive values? Then we must multiply 1 positive and 2 negative ones.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: in case we have just `2` positive values only, we'll have the second case: top value (which is positive) and two biggest negative values: `2, 1, -3, -4, -5 => 2 * -4 * -5 == 40`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework I will not provide code for you, but if you follow the following ideas, then you should be able to easily write the code:

- don't quicksort: it has a complexity of *nlogn and you can do a complexity of n
- find the three highest positive number
- find the three lowest negative number (remember -17 is lower than -12)
- store them separately
- at the end compute the product of those numbers
- beware edge cases, like (-20, -10, -4), (20, 0), don't use 0 in any product, unless you cannot reach a positive result

Happy coding!